# Can't find the infinite loop in my Haskell code

Tags: haskell

I'm learning myself Haskell, and for one exercise I have to calculate the determinant for a Matrix. I refreshed the mathematical way to do it and emulated it in code, but for some reason it's looping infinitely. I've been entering stuff into GHCi for hours trying to pinpoint what's causing it but I can't find it.

```
type Vector = [Float]
type Matrix = [Vector]

determinant :: Matrix -> Float
determinant [] = 0
determinant [[a,b],[c,d]] = (a*d) - (b*c)
determinant (vec:mat) = dethelper vec mat 0

dethelper :: Vector -> Matrix -> Int -> Float
dethelper vec mat n
  | vec == []              = 0
  | n == length vec        = 0 
  | even n                 = (vec!!n * (determinant $ map (dropAt n) mat)) - (dethelper vec mat n+1)
  | otherwise              = (vec!!n * (determinant $ map (dropAt n) mat)) + (dethelper vec mat n+1)

dropAt :: Int -> Vector -> Vector
dropAt x xs = (fst spl) ++ (tail $ snd spl)
               where spl = splitAt x xs
```

Comment: How do you invoke it? Have you tested each one of the functions?

Comment: `dethelper vec mat n+1` means `(dethelper vec mat n)+1` not `dethelper vec mat (n+1)`, which is presumably what you wanted.

Comment: @user2407038 yup, that was it. stupid mistake , thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dethelper vec mat n+1` does not work how you think it does.  It is parsed like `(dethelper vec mat n)+1`.  I think you actually want `dethelper vec mat (n+1)`